# Magento 2: Display Payment Method in Custom Sales report grid

Tags: magento2, grid, payment-methods, custom-reports

I have created the custom sales report to show required fields on the grid,

Used below code to show payment method,

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/salesfinacereport_manage_listing.xml

```
<column name="payment_method" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
    <settings>
        <filter>select</filter>
        <options class="Magento\Payment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Method\Options"/>
        <dataType>select</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Payment Method</label>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </settings>
</column>
```

here is my collection file

> Vendor/Module/Model/Resource/Products/Collection.php

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
        'main_table.order_id = secondTable.entity_id',
        '*'
    )->joinLeft( 
    ['thirdTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_address')], 
    'main_table.order_id = thirdTable.parent_id', 
    '*' 
    )->where('thirdTable.address_type=?', \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING);

    $this->addFieldToFilter('status', [ 'neq' => 'canceled']); 
    return $this;
}
```

which is not showing the payment method used for the particular order,

Can anyone help me how can we show the payment method used for the order,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payment data for the order is added under `sales_order_payment` table in the database. Yo need to use that table in your code to get the payments data in the collection.

I've updated your code for the same.

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
        'main_table.order_id = secondTable.entity_id',
        '*'
    )->joinLeft( 
        ['thirdTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_address')], 
        'main_table.order_id = thirdTable.parent_id', 
        '*' 
    )->joinLeft( 
        ['fourthTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_payment')], 
        'main_table.order_id = fourthTable.parent_id', 
        'fourthTable.method' 
    )->where('thirdTable.address_type=?', \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING);

    $this->addFieldToFilter('status', [ 'neq' => 'canceled']); 
    return $this;
}
```

Please give it a try.

**EDIT:**

Get Payment method title from the method code

```
/**
 * Payment Helper Data
 *
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_paymentHelper;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
) {
    $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
}

/**
 * Get key-value pair of all payment methods
 * key = method code & value = method name
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getAllPaymentMethodsList() 
{
    return $this->_paymentHelper->getPaymentMethodList();
}
```

Sample output of the `getAllPaymentMethodsList()` will like

```
Array
(
    [vault] => 
    [substitution] => 
    [banktransfer] => Bank Transfer Payment
    [cashondelivery] => Cash On Delivery
    [checkmo] => Check / Money order
    [payflowpro] => Credit Card
    [payflow_link] => Credit Card
    [payflow_advanced] => Credit Card
    [braintree] => Credit Card (Braintree)
    [authorizenet_directpost] => Credit Card Direct Post (Authorize.net)
    [free] => No Payment Information Required
    [braintree_paypal] => PayPal (Braintree)
    [paypal_billing_agreement] => PayPal Billing Agreement
    [payflow_express_bml] => PayPal Credit
    [paypal_express_bml] => PayPal Credit
    [paypal_express] => PayPal Express Checkout
    [payflow_express] => PayPal Express Checkout Payflow Edition
    [hosted_pro] => Payment by cards or by PayPal account
    [purchaseorder] => Purchase Order
    [braintree_cc_vault] => Stored Cards (Braintree)
    [payflowpro_cc_vault] => Stored Cards (Payflow Pro)
)
```

You can get the payment method title by checking the method code in the array.

**Edit:**

Updating collection to get Invoice Id in the custom collection.

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
        'main_table.order_id = secondTable.entity_id',
        '*'
    )->joinLeft( 
        ['thirdTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_address')], 
        'main_table.order_id = thirdTable.parent_id', 
        '*' 
    )->joinLeft( 
        ['fourthTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order_payment')], 
        'main_table.order_id = fourthTable.parent_id', 
        'fourthTable.method' 
    )->joinLeft( 
        ['fifthTable' => $this->getTable('sales_invoice_grid')], 
        'main_table.order_id = fifthTable.parent_id', 
        'fifthTable.increment_id' 
    )->where('thirdTable.address_type=?', \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::ADDRESS_TYPE_SHIPPING);

    $this->addFieldToFilter('status', [ 'neq' => 'canceled']); 
    return $this;
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: hi @Sumit, thanks it worked but one small change, this will display method like checkmo, etc, can we display full description? any possiblities?

Comment: Perfect, yes you can display the Payment method label from the payment method code when display in the reports grid with your custom module.

Comment: can you update me the code to display payment method label from method code?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Its fine, but how can i render label in my grid?

Comment: How do you render data in the reports grid?

Comment: In listing xml file, i posted in the question, Also how can we display invoice number please?

Comment: hi sumit, that i made it work, my last requirement is to show invoice increment id also, how that can be shown in grid?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a review @Manjunath

Comment: Thanks @Sumit, I made it differently, by sales_invoice table